# How Azure DevOps Project Administrator is assigned

Tags: azure-devops

When a new Project is created in DevOps organization, how Project administrators is assigned to that Project. At the time of creation, there is no input parameter to specify administrators.

How to assign a DevOps group as Project administrators using automation.

Answer (score 0):

When someone create a new team project, he/she would be the Project administrator by default. There is no automatic process to add project administrators during project creation. To give a user/group project administration permission, complete the following steps:

1. Open the web portal and choose the project where you want to add users or groups.
2. Choose **Project settings** and then **Permissions**.
3. Choose **Project Administrators** group, **Members**, and then **Add**.

[image]

4. Enter the name of the user/group account into the text box and then select from the match that appears.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Cece.

> How to assign a DevOps group as Project administrators using automation.

As a workaround, we could create project and configure the Project administrators via power shell and rest API.

**a.** List template and get template type id

```
Get https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/work/processes?api-version=6.1-preview.2
```

**b.** Create project

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/projects?api-version=6.1-preview.4
```

Request Body:

```
{
  "name": "{Project name}",
  "description": "{description}",
  "capabilities": {
    "versioncontrol": {
      "sourceControlType": "Git"
    },
    "processTemplate": {
      "templateTypeId": "{template Type Id}"
    }
  }
}
```

**c.** List group and get Project Administrators group ID

Note: `originId` is group ID

```
https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{Org name}/_apis/graph/groups?api-version=6.0-preview.1
```

**d.** List all users and get member Id

Note: `id` is member Id

```
https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/{Org name}/_apis/userentitlements?api-version=6.0-preview.3
```

**e.** [Add a member to a Group.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/memberentitlementmanagement/members/add?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)

```
PUT https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/GroupEntitlements/{groupId}/members/{memberId}?api-version=5.1-preview.1
```

Result:

[image]